# Converting single index pandas df to multi-index df and then grouping all rows with the same index together on separate lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a df that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Alice', 'Carol', 'Alice', 'Carol', 'Matt'],
                   'Address': ['123 A St', '123 B St', '123 C St', '123 A St', '123 C St', '456 X St', '123 C St', '123 M St'],
                   'State': ['AZ', 'TX', 'CA', 'AZ', 'CA', 'AZ', 'CA', 'MA'],
                   'Car': ['GMC', 'Mazda', 'Tesla', 'Honda', 'Nissan', 'Subaru', 'Mazda', 'Buick'],
                   'Miles': [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888]})

# Display df
display(df)
```

**Goal**

I would like for the output to be a multi-index df using 'Name', 'Address', and 'State' that would look as follows:

| Name | Address | State | Car | Miles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 123 A St | AZ | GMC | 1111 |
|  |  |  | Honda | 4444 |
| Alice | 456 X St | AZ | Subaru | 6666 |
| Bob | 123 B St | TX | Mazda | 2222 |
| Carol | 123 C St | CA | Tesla | 3333 |
|  |  |  | Nissan | 5555 |
|  |  |  | Mazda | 7777 |
| Matt | 123 M St | MA | Buick | 8888 |

**Code attempted**

I tried the following code, but it does not group all rows of data with the same multi-index values:

```
df = df.set_index(keys=['Name', 'Address', 'State'])
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your index after setting it, however you will end up with all the `Alice` values grouped together:

```
df.set_index(keys=['Name', 'Address', 'State']).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                         Car  Miles
Name  Address  State
Alice 123 A St AZ        GMC   1111
               AZ      Honda   4444
      456 X St AZ     Subaru   6666
Bob   123 B St TX      Mazda   2222
Carol 123 C St CA      Tesla   3333
               CA     Nissan   5555
               CA      Mazda   7777
Matt  123 M St MA      Buick   8888
```

To get something close to the result you want, you need to index on `['Address', 'State', 'Name']` and then sort on the `Name` first:

```
df.set_index(keys=['Address', 'State', 'Name']).sort_index(level=2)
```

Output:

```
                         Car  Miles
Address  State Name
123 A St AZ    Alice     GMC   1111
               Alice   Honda   4444
456 X St AZ    Alice  Subaru   6666
123 B St TX    Bob     Mazda   2222
123 C St CA    Carol   Tesla   3333
               Carol  Nissan   5555
               Carol   Mazda   7777
123 M St MA    Matt    Buick   8888
```